# Cant make elements follow the GridLayout

Tags: java, android, xml

I'm trying to make that my element that are inside my gridlayout showup, but it's not showing the way i want. I'm trying to use weights to make the elements apper in the screen, but its not working too. Heres my xml:

```
 <RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_rowSpan="11"
    android:layout_rowWeight="0.2"
    android:layout_columnSpan="9"
    android:layout_columnWeight="0.2125"
    android:background="@drawable/rounded_static_border">

    <GridLayout
        android:id="@+id/relative"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/btn_height"
        android:background="@drawable/rounded_press_btn"
        android:columnCount="9"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:rowCount="1">

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/leftsideImageButton"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/btn_width"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@drawable/rounded_hardpress_btn"
            android:padding="@dimen/icon_padding"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:src="@drawable/icone_anterior_turquesa" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_rowWeight="0.2"
            android:layout_columnWeight="0.083"
            android:visibility="invisible" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_display_message"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@drawable/rounded_hardpress_btn"
            android:fontFamily="@font/robotoregular"
            android:layout_columnSpan="5"
            android:layout_columnWeight="0.58"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Buscando..."
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textSize="@dimen/text_size" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_rowWeight="0.2"
            android:layout_columnWeight="0.083"
            android:visibility="invisible" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/rightSideImageButton"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/btn_width"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@drawable/rounded_hardpress_btn"
            android:layout_columnSpan="1"
            android:padding="@dimen/icon_padding"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:src="@drawable/icone_proxima_turquesa" />

    </GridLayout>


    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/wifi_list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@id/relative"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/rounded_static_border"
        android:dividerHeight="10sp"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textSize="@dimen/text_size" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

this is how i want it to look

[This is how i want to show my elements](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WJKYL.png)

and this is what i'm having right now:

[result till now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a29Pv.png)

OBS: All my layout and elements are inside of a big gridlayout.